# Dijkstra's algorithm implemented in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to implement [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) in an Excel VBA Add-In and built it to be used as follows:

1. Define a list of paths with distances between points. This list needs to contain 3 headings that are used as flags to pick up where the list is. The 3 headings are `!dijk:dat:from`, `!dijk:dat:to` and `!dijk:dat:dist`
2. Specify from which point to which point you want to go. This is indicated with flags to the left of the cell. The flags are `!dijk:get:from` and `!dijk:get:to`
3. If the list of paths is on a different sheet, specify which sheet it is on by putting the name of the sheet in a cell next to a cell with the text `!dijk:dat`
4. Specify where the output should go. This is defined with a flag at the top left of where it should go. The flag is `!dijk:steps`
5. Push a button in the Ribbon that triggers `Sub sCalcDijkstra()` in a module in my Add-In

An example of a dummy sheet I used for testing:

[image: Example Sheet]

This is the procedure that does all the work:

```
Sub sCalcDijkstra()
    'Calculate the shortest path between 2 points

    Dim vError As String
    Dim vRange As Range
    Dim vRangeDat As Range
    Dim vRow As Long
    Dim vRowDatHead As Long
    Dim vRowSteps As Long
    Dim vRowFirst As Long
    Dim vRowCount As Long
    Dim vRowCountDat As Long
    Dim vCol As Long
    Dim vColDatFrom As Long
    Dim vColDatTo As Long
    Dim vColDatDist As Long
    Dim vColSteps As Long
    Dim vColFirst As Long
    Dim vColCount As Long
    Dim vColCountDat As Long
    Dim vCell As String
    Dim vCellFrom As String
    Dim vCellTo As String
    Dim vValDist As Double
    Dim vParFrom As String
    Dim vParTo As String
    Dim vParDat As String
    Dim vDist As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim vCurNode As String
    Dim vCurDist As Double
    Dim vCurDistTo As Double
    Dim vSteps() As String

    On Error GoTo 0
    vError = ""

    'Check that there is a workbook open
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then vError = "You need to open a workbook in order to do this"
    If vError <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Get the settings from the current sheet
    Set vRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    vRowCount = vRange.Rows.Count
    vColCount = vRange.Columns.Count
    vRowFirst = vRange.Row
    vColFirst = vRange.Column
    vRowSteps = 0
    vColSteps = 0
    vParFrom = ""
    vParTo = ""
    vParDat = ""
    For vRow = 1 To vRowCount
        For vCol = 1 To vColCount
            vCell = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            vCell = Trim(UCase(vRange.Cells(vRow, vCol).Value))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If vCell = "!DIJK:GET:FROM" Then
                vParFrom = Trim(UCase(vRange.Cells(vRow, vCol + 1).Value))
            ElseIf vCell = "!DIJK:GET:TO" Then
                vParTo = Trim(UCase(vRange.Cells(vRow, vCol + 1).Value))
            ElseIf vCell = "!DIJK:DAT" Then
                vParDat = Trim(UCase(vRange.Cells(vRow, vCol + 1).Value))
            ElseIf vCell = "!DIJK:STEPS" Then
                vRowSteps = vRow
                vColSteps = vCol
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If vParFrom = "" Then vError = vError & "Need to specify a Source with the parameter !dijk:get:from" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vParTo = "" Then vError = vError & "Need to specify a Destination with the parameter !dijk:get:to" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vRowSteps = 0 Then vError = vError & "Need to designate an area to print the results with the parameter !dijk:steps" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vError <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Clean up the output area
    vRange.Range(vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + 2 - vRowFirst, vColSteps + 1 - vColFirst).Address, vRange.Cells(vRowCount + vRowFirst - 1, vColSteps + 3 - vColFirst).Address).ClearContents

    'Get the paths from the data sheet
    If vParDat = "" Then
        Set vRangeDat = vRange
    Else
        Set vRangeDat = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(vParDat).UsedRange
    End If
    vRowCountDat = vRangeDat.Rows.Count
    vColCountDat = vRangeDat.Columns.Count
    vRowDatHead = 0
    vColDatFrom = 0
    vColDatTo = 0
    vColDatDist = 0
    For vRow = 1 To vRowCountDat
        For vCol = 1 To vColCountDat
            vCell = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            vCell = Trim(UCase(vRangeDat.Cells(vRow, vCol).Value))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If vCell = "!DIJK:DAT:FROM" Then
                vRowDatHead = vRow
                vColDatFrom = vCol
            ElseIf vCell = "!DIJK:DAT:TO" Then
                vRowDatHead = vRow
                vColDatTo = vCol
            ElseIf vCell = "!DIJK:DAT:DIST" Then
                vRowDatHead = vRow
                vColDatDist = vCol
            End If
        Next
        If vRowDatHead > 0 Then Exit For
    Next

    If vColDatFrom = 0 Then vError = vError & "Data sheet is missing !dijk:dat:from column" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vColDatTo = 0 Then vError = vError & "Data sheet is missing !dijk:dat:to column" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vColDatDist = 0 Then vError = vError & "Data sheet is missing !dijk:dat:dist column" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vError <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set vDist = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For vRow = vRowDatHead + 1 To vRowCountDat
        vCellFrom = ""
        vCellTo = ""
        vValDist = -1
        On Error Resume Next
        vCellFrom = Trim(UCase(vRangeDat.Cells(vRow, vColDatFrom).Value))
        vCellTo = Trim(UCase(vRangeDat.Cells(vRow, vColDatTo).Value))
        vValDist = Val(Trim(UCase(vRangeDat.Cells(vRow, vColDatDist).Value)))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If vCellFrom <> "" And vCellTo <> "" And vValDist >= 0 Then
            If Not vDist.Exists(vCellFrom) Then Set vDist.Item(vCellFrom) = New Scripting.Dictionary
            If Not vDist.Exists(vCellTo) Then Set vDist.Item(vCellTo) = New Scripting.Dictionary
            vDist(vCellFrom).Item(vCellTo) = vValDist
            If Not vDist(vCellTo).Exists(vCellFrom) Then vDist(vCellTo).Item(vCellFrom) = vValDist
        End If
    Next

    If Not vDist.Exists(vParFrom) Then vError = vError & "Source " & vParFrom & " not listed in data" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If Not vDist.Exists(vParTo) Then vError = vError & "Destination " & vParTo & " not listed in data" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    If vError <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Calculate the shortest path
    For Each vKey In vDist.Keys()
        vDist(vKey).Item("!dist") = -1
        vDist(vKey).Item("!scan") = False
        vDist(vKey).Item("!steps") = ""
    Next

    vDist(vParFrom).Item("!dist") = 0
    vDist(vParFrom).Item("!steps") = vParFrom

    Do While True
        vCurNode = ""
        vCurDist = 0
        For Each vKey In vDist.Keys()
            If vDist(vKey)("!scan") = False Then
                If vDist(vKey)("!dist") >= 0 Then
                    If vCurNode = "" Or vCurDist > vDist(vKey)("!dist") Then
                        vCurNode = vKey
                        vCurDist = vDist(vKey)("!dist")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If vCurNode = "" Then Exit Do
        If vCurNode = vParTo Then Exit Do
        vDist(vCurNode).Item("!scan") = True
        For Each vKey In vDist(vCurNode).Keys()
            If Left(vKey, 1) <> "!" And vKey <> vCurNode Then
                vCurDistTo = vCurDist + vDist(vCurNode)(vKey)
                If vDist(vKey)("!dist") < 0 Or vCurDistTo < vDist(vKey)("!dist") Then
                    vDist(vKey).Item("!dist") = vCurDistTo
                    vDist(vKey).Item("!steps") = vDist(vCurNode)("!steps") & "!" & vKey
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Loop

    'Print the result
    If vDist(vParTo)("!dist") < 0 Then
        vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + 1, vColSteps).Value = "No path found from source to destination"
    Else
        vSteps = Split(vDist(vParTo)("!steps"), "!")
        For vRow = 1 To UBound(vSteps)
            vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + vRow, vColSteps).Value = vSteps(vRow - 1)
            vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + vRow, vColSteps + 1).Value = vSteps(vRow)
            vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + vRow, vColSteps + 2).Value = vDist(vSteps(vRow - 1))(vSteps(vRow))
        Next
        vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + vRow, vColSteps).Value = "Total:"
        vRange.Cells(vRowSteps + vRow, vColSteps + 2).Value = vDist(vParTo)("!dist")
    End If

    'Done
    MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Path and Distance"
    GoTo Finalize

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox vError, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"

Finalize:
    Set vDist = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code works, but I would like some feedback on the following aspects:

- How can I make this easier and more intuitive for a user? I know I can use named ranges instead of flags, but I would prefer to keep it more visibly obvious what the code is using
- How can I apply the DRY principle more here. I'm repeating the same patterns all the time, but it seems like the details vary too much for me to just stick something like the nested for loops into a function
- I use `Scripting.Dictionary` for almost everything due to it's flexibility and simply due to the fact that I am comfortable with how it works, but I suspect there may be better data structures that I can use which work better for this use case
- At the heart of this is the `Do While True` loop which is probably a horribly inefficient way to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm. How can I make it more efficient?
- Any help/critique is greatly appreciated. I taught myself VBA with the help of Google and I may be doing some bad things I never even realised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a humungous procedure you got there. It's all in one piece and it's following a lot of conventions from older VBA code that you should not let become a habit.

The first of these "conventions" is to declare every variable at the top of the block they're scoped to. This is a relic of "ye olden days" where it was important to know up front what things were in a procedure and how you could refer to them. See what that does to the readability of your code on a screen that is not in portrait orientation:

[image: declarations section from the question screenshotted]

This is... not really useful, because I can't even remotely tell what variable is needed where and even **whether** it's needed.

**Declare variables as close as possible to their usage**.
This has the added benefit of reducing the mental strain when reading the code. You don't need to remember every variable declaration, only those in close proximity to understand the code.

While we're at that section: I noticed that you prefixed every single one of these variables with a `v`, most likely for "Variable". Don't do that. This adds no useful information to the name of the variable and should frankly speaking be unnecessary.

> ```
> 'Check that there is a workbook open
> If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then vError = "You need to open a workbook in order to do this"
> If vError <> "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler
> ```

Let's rewrite this a bit. For one the comment is a lie, this doesn't check that a workbook is open, it checks that the ActiveSheet property of the global Application object is not Nothing. In addition you're making this somewhat harder to read by forcing yourself into single-line if-statements:

```
If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
    vError = "You need to open a workbook and select a sheet in order to do this"
    GoTo ErrorHandler
End If
```

---

Doing all the work is long and tedious. This code can benefit a lot from extracting subroutines into actual subroutines or Functions. Consider encapsulating blocks of code that have an explanatory comment into their own function:

```
Sub SolveDijkstra()
    If Not CheckWorkbook() Then Exit Sub

    Dim settings As DijkstraSettings
    Set settings = GetSettingsFromCurrentSheet()

    If Not CheckSettings(settings) Then Exit Sub

    CleanOutputArea()
    Dim graph As Graph
    Set graph = GetPathsFromDataSheet()

    If Not CheckGraph(graph) Then Exit Sub

    Dim path As DijkstraSolution
    Set path = Dijkstra(graph, settings)

    If path.HasSolution Then
        WritePathToOutput(path)
    Else
        WriteErrorToOutput("No path found from source to destination")
    End If

    MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Path and Distance"
End Sub
```

This "reimagination" has the clear benefit of allowing us to abstract the tedious separate steps into methods and objects. We don't need to understand the **10** different loops to grasp what this sub does.

Note that this also sidesteps the usage of GoTo which is ... problematic in some contexts.

---

In closing I want to explicitly call out stuff I noticed as outstanding:

- You always access a cell's value explicitly through `Value` :+1:
- You use a dictionary to keep track of the cost for a given node
- You reinstate error handling after `On Error Resume Next` statements and seem to have tried to keep OERN areas as small as possible
- You validate your input and have a pretty clean way of getting it from your sheet

What's missing to take your VBA coding to the next step is the use of objects and user-defined types as well as noting that you don't need to reuse a block of code to extract it.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. I agree with all your points. Time to learn about user-defined objects in VBA. I'm not very familiar with objects in VBA, but have used them in other languages

Answer (score 3):

### Question 1

> How can I make this easier and more intuitive for a user? I know I can use named ranges instead of flags, but I would prefer to keep it more visibly obvious what the code is using

The first thing that I would do is rename all data headers. I understand that you wanted an unique identifier that "**!dijk:dat:from**" to me is not at all intuitive to me.   After studying Dijkstra's algorithm I came back to determined that it is represents `Dijkstra's - data - From` nodes (vertices).   Although they make perfect sense, I also don't like `From` and `To`.  I'm not an authority but I think that there is no inherent direction to the connection of two nodes in a graph.

Alternate Column Headers:

- !dijk:dat:from Node, Node1, Vertex, Vertex1
- !dijk:dat:to Neighbor, Node2, Vertex2
- !dijk:dat:dist Distance
- !dijk:get:from Origin
- !dijk:get:to Destination
- !dijk:steps Path

[image]

### Question 2

> How can I apply the DRY principle more here. I'm repeating the same patterns all the time, but it seems like the details vary too much for me to just stick something like the nested for loops into a function

There isn't really any unnecessary repeated code.

↓This loop↓ is repeated twice but the second loop relies on information gathered from the first loop.

> ```
> For vRow = 1 To vRowCount
>     For vCol = 1 To vColCount
> ```

### Question 3

> I use Scripting.Dictionary for almost everything due to it's flexibility and simply due to the fact that I am comfortable with how it works, but I suspect there may be better data structures that I can use which work better for this use case

A custom Node class would have made it easier work out the logic but it is not necessary.

### Pseudo Class: GraphNode

```
Option Explicit
Const Infinity As Long = 2147483647
Private Type Members
    NodeKey As String
    NeighborKey As String
    Distance As Long
End Type
Private m As Members

Public Sub Init(NodeKey As String, Optional NeighborKey As String, Optional Distance As Long = Infinity)
    m.NodeKey = NodeKey
    m.NeighborKey = NeighborKey
    m.Distance = Distance
End Sub

Public Function getKey() As String
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    getKey = m.NodeKey = NodeKey
End Function

Public Function getDistance(Node As GraphNode) As Long
        getDistance = m.Distance
End Function

Public Function UpdateDistance(Node As GraphNode) As Boolean
    If Node.getDistance < m.Distance Then
        UpdateDistance = True
        m.Distance = Node.getDistance
    End If
End Function
```

I would make some changes in the way that you use the dictionaries.

Using these keys "!dist", "!steps", "!scan" as properties works very well.

> ```
> vDist(vKey)("!dist")
> vDist(vKey).Item("!dist")
> vDist(vKey).Item("!steps")
> vDist(vKey).Item("!scan")
> ```

I would use constants instead.  This will not only make the code easier to read but enable you to use intellisense with them.

[image]

`Item` can be omitted because the default member of a Scripting Dictionary is `Items()`.

> ```
>  vDist(vKey).Item("!dist")
> vDist(vKey)("!dist")
> ```

Since `Items()` takes a string as an argument we can use the Bang operator to pass a string key to `Items()` and return the it's value.

> ```
> vDist(vKey)![!dist]
> ```

The bracket are necessary because `!dist` is not a valid variable name.  Removing `!` from the variable names will allow you to do this:

> ```
> vDist(vKey)!dist
> ```

### Question 4

> At the heart of this is the Do While True loop which is probably a horribly inefficient way to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm. How can I make it more efficient?

Dijkstra's Algorithm requires a `Do` or a `While` loop this is unavoidable.  Implementing the [min-priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) meationed in the article you linked would make it more efficient but that is out of the scope of a review.

[Wikipedia - Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

> A min-priority queue is an abstract data type that provides 3 basic operations : add_with_priority(), decrease_priority() and extract_min(). As mentioned earlier, using such a data structure can lead to faster computing times than using a basic queue.

### Add Template

Creating a subroutine to add a template worksheet would make the setup easier for both you and the users.  Using constants for the Column Headers and working with tables would also simplify things.

```
Const NodeHeader As String = "Node", NeighborHeader As String = "Neighbor", DistanceHeader As String = "Distance"
Const OriginHeader As String = "Origin", DestinationHeader As String = "Destination"
Const Distance As String = "Distance", Path As String = "Path", Visited As String = "Visited"

Sub AddTemplate()
    Dim TableRange As Range
    With Worksheets.Add
        ' Add Graph NodeList Table
        .Range("B1").Value = "Graph - Node List"
        Set TableRange = .Range("B2").Resize(1, 3)
        TableRange.Value = Array(NodeHeader, NeighborHeader, DistanceHeader)
        .ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, TableRange, , xlYes

        ' Add Settings Table
        .Range("F1").Value = "Settings"
        Set TableRange = .Range("F2").Resize(1, 2)
        TableRange.Value = Array(OriginHeader, DestinationHeader)
        .ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, TableRange, , xlYes

        ' Add Results Table
        .Range("F5").Value = "Results"
        Set TableRange = .Range("F6").Resize(1, 3)
        TableRange.Value = Array(OriginHeader, DestinationHeader, DistanceHeader)
        .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TableRange, , xlYes).ShowTotals = True
        TableRange.Cells(3, 3).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[Distance])"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: I dislike the suggestion of the bang operator. Other than that, this looks pretty good :)